# How to query the average value of documents in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume that student grade information is stored in my documents, and the information includes the grades of each subjects.

The index mapping like this :

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 18,
  "math_scores": 90,
  "english_scores": 70,
  "physics_scores": 80,
  .....
}
```

Now I need to find people whose average scores in physics, mathematics, and English are greater than 90.

There are more than 30 subjects. The average score of a different subject is required each time, so I can't save average score in ElasticSearch.

Comment: how would you find people with average scores? You can calculate average score across all people or find people with scores greater than 90. Please clarify

Comment: @Nick I need to find people with average scores. But I don't know how to do. Now I find that it seems impossible

Comment: you can run https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html to get the avg for that field